# In Java Swing, is there a way to toggle ButtonGroups being mutually exclusive?

Tags: java, swing, buttongroup, jtogglebutton

From what I understand, if you want to have to select one option, you put it in a ButtonGroup, and if you don't, you don't use a ButtonGroup. But I want it so that multiple can be selected but only if you selected something else in another area. Is there anything I can do besides remove each element from the button group one at a time?

Comment: So, if I understand what you're asking, you want a group of JButtons where only one can be selected.  If you select something else, then the group of JButtons allow multiple selections.  Is this correct?  What's the something else selected?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything I can do besides remove each element from the button group one at a time?

1. Manually removing buttons seems simple enough to do.
2. Or you could extend `ButtonGroup` and create a `removeAllButtons()` method. By extending `ButtonGroup`. You will have access to the `Vector` that holds all the buttons in the group. Then you just invoke the `removeAllElement()`method of the Vector.
3. You could create a custom `ButtonModel`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44183140/131872 as an example of this approach. You could modify the logic such that a size value of "-1" indicates there is no selection limit.